# Reading csv file in chunks from s3 within a AWS lambda function

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, csv, aws-lambda

I’m trying to implement step functions or recursive aws lambda function my basic idea is to read csv file from s3 with range bytes and process the records then invoke my next lambda function with updated start and end offsets to read next chunk the problem is when I’m doing this the csv file is split sometimes in between lines I’m facing difficulty to reconstruct the offsets to read does anyone have any ideas or pointers how to resolve this scenario

Comment: "the csv file is split sometimes in between lines" -- can you illustrate this with an example that shows the problem?

Answer (score 1):

How about you read a range of bytes, *x-y*, steps backwards to find the last newline position and change your *y* value to be that byte and discard the bytes after that. Then your next range request begins at *y*+1.